# Incrementing a single database row field multiple times at once while making sure that all changes are saved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET 5 Web API application using EF Core with Npgsql (PostgreSQL).
I'm trying to implement a file download tracker that increments some fields in my database when a file is requested.

Let's say I have this object:

```cs
public class Stats
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long DownloadCount { get; set; }
}
```

This application will obviously have many users requesting many **different** files at the same time, resulting in *lots of changes made to the same value* **for each file**. Now, I'm wondering whether this type of thing is already implemented in the internal change tracker or not.

If it isn't, how can I implement it in a way that will make sure that every request is counted?

Comment: the actual `DownloadCount` should be managed ***in-memory*** so that you can lock on it and add up the value safely. The final value can be updated to the database with a delay (depending on your requirement about the exact count that should be tracked).

Comment: And this would be done in a background service of some sort? (as you can see, I'm not very experienced with this stuff)

Comment: I would not implement any locking as that would adversely affect concurrent requests and scalability. Consider using [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0) to keep track of download count and a background worker to periodically update the stats.

Comment: I get the incrementing part, but I don't know how and where I would store the stats in memory.

Comment: Any static property would be shared between threads. Probably overkill, but you could also drop a message on a queue each time there is a download and let a separate process pick up each queue message sequentially to update the stats. If you are in Azure, an Azure Queue combined with Azure functions would be dirt cheap for this solution.

Comment: I see, so I would queue the value change and the background worker would go through the update tasks sequentially and update each entry.

Comment: In that scenario I meant just increment a static int on some class with Interlocked.Increment and the background worker would update the stats and reset the int to zero. You could miss a few downloads that way though, depending on how fast requests are coming in, and if the process recycles for some reason you would lose data. Another way would be to write a stored procedure that adds one to the value and you call it on every download so the database handles the synchronization.

Comment: This would be the case if I only had **one** download counter to track, but what I actually meant is **multiple** files that need to get the download count tracked. I'm going to edit the question so it makes more sense

Comment: @TimmSkiller you have a queue and that queue basically can contain data for all files almost including just the file id. So the processor can base on the file id to count each of type. You don't need to waste a lot of memory. Again, no matter what you have to do, where you do must be ***in-memory***. I talked about locking at first, but actually that's a general term (guarding against multiple execution from jumping into a ***critical section*** at the same time).

Comment: Problem is that this is a complete feature to implement, not a problem to solve. :) For a simple implementation you need a hosted service that runs an action on a timer. Then you need a separate singleton service (or one with a static property) for maintaining the count increases for each file in a thread-safe manner. Then you increment the counts through this second service. And periodically write out the counters into DB via the first service, which creates a scope at each run and requests the context and this second service inside that scope. Plus maybe handling db write concurrency too.